# Adding search bar of UISearchController as a subview of a view using auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a view controller class, in whose xib I have added 3 entities: container view, a search bar container view and a button. I have arranged the search bar container and the button at the top of the controller's view using auto layout constraints on the storyboard. Together they span the entire width of the view and take up a height equal to 44px. Below them lies the container view whose top is aligned with the bottom of the search bar container view. Following is the viewDidLoad and other related methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addTableView];

    self.searchControllerInternal = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

    self.searchControllerInternal.delegate = self;
    self.searchControllerInternal.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchControllerInternal.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchControllerInternal.searchBar.delegate = self;

    [self addSearchControllerSearchBarToView];

}

    -(void)addSearchControllerSearchBarToView
    {
        UISearchBar *pSearchBar = self.searchControllerInternal.searchBar;

        self.searchBarContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self.searchBarContainerView addSubview:pSearchBar];

        pSearchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self addSearchBarConstraints];
    }

-(void)addSearchBarConstraints
{
    UISearchBar *pSearchBar = self.searchControllerInternal.searchBar;

    {
        NSLayoutConstraint *pConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pSearchBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.searchBarContainerView
                                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                      multiplier:1
                                                                        constant:0];

        [self.searchBarContainerView addConstraint:pConstraint];

        self.searchBarTopConstraint = pConstraint;
    }

    {
        NSLayoutConstraint *pLeadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pSearchBar
                                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                 toItem:self.searchBarContainerView
                                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                             multiplier:1
                                                                               constant:0];

        [self.searchBarContainerView addConstraint:pLeadingConstraint];
    }

    {
        NSLayoutConstraint *pTrailingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pSearchBar
                                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                  toItem:self.searchBarContainerView
                                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                                constant:0];

        [self.searchBarContainerView addConstraint:pTrailingConstraint];
    }

    {
        NSLayoutConstraint *pBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pSearchBar
                                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                  toItem:self.searchBarContainerView
                                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                                constant:0];

        [self.searchBarContainerView addConstraint:pBottomConstraint];
    }


}
```

The view loads properly. However, on tapping the search bar, the search bar moves out of its container view. The search bar container view lies just below the status bar, where the search bar should also be, but it has actually moved out of the visible area. Why is this happening? Also, if the dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation is set to TRUE, the app crashes if user taps anywhere on the screen while search is active, saying that *"The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint"*

Comment: You may want to create own `UISearchBar`, don't add search bar of `UISearchController` as a subview of a view.

Comment: I can do that. But how am I going to associate it with the search controller? I am using the delegate methods that come with the UISearchController